# I am working on an encryption thing in JavaScript and I need the code to run the print and test commands at the same time. Any pointers?

Tags: javascript, encryption

This is my code so far.  I need to be able to test and print all at once.  It doesn't give me any errors, but output xjxjxj when I inputted baba.  Note, b is j and a is x.  It needs to run all of the print commands at once.  Don't mind the first few variables, that was a mistake I forgot to get rid of.  Keep it mind, that I also need to write code that will decrypt the encrypted code.  Also, it won't account for spaces, so any pointers on that as well.  Thanks!

```js
var a = /a/g, b=/b/g, c=/c/g, d=/d/g, e=/e/g, f=/f/g, g=/g/g, h=/h/g, i=/i/g, j=/j/g, k=/k/g, l=/l/g, m=/m/g, n=/n/g, o=/o/g, p=/p/g, q=/q/g, r=/r/g, s=/s/g, t=/t/g, u=/u/g, v=/v/g, w=/w/g, x=/x/g, y=/y/g, z=/z/g
var answer = prompt('What cipher are you going to use 1 - 26', 1)
var encrypt = prompt('Enter text you want encrypted', 'abc')
if (answer = 1) {
 for (var gv = 0; gv < Object.keys(encrypt).length; gv++) {
  var result = a.test(encrypt)
  var result1 = b.test(encrypt)
  var result2 = c.test(encrypt)
  var result3 = d.test(encrypt)
  var result4 = e.test(encrypt)
  var result5 = f.test(encrypt)
  var result6 = g.test(encrypt)
  var result7 = h.test(encrypt)
  var result8 = i.test(encrypt)
  var result9 = j.test(encrypt)
  var result10 = k.test(encrypt)
  var result11 = l.test(encrypt)
  var result12 = m.test(encrypt)
  var result13 = n.test(encrypt)
  var result14 = o.test(encrypt)
  var result15 = p.test(encrypt)
  var result16 = q.test(encrypt)
  var result17 = r.test(encrypt)
  var result18 = s.test(encrypt)
  var result19 = t.test(encrypt)
  var result20 = u.test(encrypt)
  var result21 = v.test(encrypt)
  var result22 = w.test(encrypt)
  var result23 = x.test(encrypt)
  var result24 = y.test(encrypt)
  var result25 = z.test(encrypt)

  if(result === true) { 
    
    document.write('x') 
    result=false   //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
  }
   if(result1 === true) {

     document.write('j') 
        result1=false
  }
   if(result2 === true) {
     document.write('p')  
     result2=false
     
  }
   if(result3 === true) { 
   
     document.write('s')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X 
      result3=false                 //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C M Y 
  }
   if(result4 === true) {
    
     document.write('d')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X 
     result4=false                     //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C M 
  }
   if(result5 === true) {
  
     document.write('a')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X 
        result5=false                   //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C 
  }
   if(result6 === true) { 
   
     document.write('u')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X 
     result6=false                //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C M Y T 
  }
   if(result7 === true) {
     
     document.write('o')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X 
     result7=false                   //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C M Y 
  }
   if(result8 === true) {
     
     document.write('w')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X
     result8=false                     //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C M 
  }
   if(result9 === true) {    
     
     document.write('k')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X 
     result9=false                //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C M Y T 
  }
   if(result10 === true) {
     
     document.write('q')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X 
    result10=false                     //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C M 
  }
   if(result11 === true) {
     
     document.write('v')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X 
     result11=false                     //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C 
  }
   if(result12 === true) {
   
     document.write('g')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X 
     result12=false                      //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C 
  }
   if(result13 === true) {
     
     document.write('l')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X 
     result13=false                     //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C 
  }
   if(result14 === true) { 
     
     document.write('n')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X 
     result14=false                    //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C M 
  }
   if(result15 === true) {
    
     document.write('b')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X 
      result15=false                     //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C 
  }
   if(result16 === true) {
     
     document.write('e')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X 
     result16=false                    //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C M 
  }
   if(result17 === true) {
     
     document.write('c')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X 
     result17=false                    //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C M 
  }
   if(result18 === true) {
     
     document.write('m')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X 
     result18=false                     //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C 
  } 
  if(result19 === true) {   
  
    document.write('y')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X 
      result19=false                   //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C M 
  }
   if(result20 === true) { 
     
     document.write('t')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X 
    result20=false                     //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C M 
  }
   if(result21 === true) { 
     
     document.write('h')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X 
     result21=false                    //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C M 
  }
   if(result22 === true) {  
     
     document.write('f')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X
    result22=false                    //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C M
  }
   if(result23 === true) {
     
     document.write('i')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X 
    result23=false                   //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C M Y 
  }
   if(result24 === true) {
     
     document.write('z')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X 
    result24=false                   //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C M Y 
  }
   if(result25 === true) {
     
     document.write('r')     //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X 
     result25=false                   //X J P S D A U O W K Q V G L N B E C M 
  }
} 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thats all really.

Comment: Another problem that has arisen is that I can't figure out how to decrypt, would I just reverse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps:

```
// Well, let's start with a somewhat abridged version of your code:
// ...and walk through what that means.
// First, set up your cypher. I'm using an object here, for quick readability, but you could just as easily make it a flat array: ['G', 'P', 'X', 'E', ...]
let cypher = {A:"G",B:"L",C:"Z",D:"E",E:"Y",F:"R",G:"D",H:"N",I:"K",J:"W",K:"J",L:"B",M:"Q",N:"F",O:"S",P:"C",Q:"V",R:"X",S:"I",T:"O",U:"M",V:"T",W:"A",X:"U",Y:"H",Z:"P"};

// Fire off your prompts
var answer  = prompt('What cipher are you going to use 1 - 26', 1);
var encrypt = prompt('Enter text you want encrypted', 'abc');
var output  = "";
// And begin:
if (answer == 1) {
    // First, lets make sure the input is all uppercase. Otherwise your cypher needs to be double the size you're looking at.
    encrypt = encrypt.toUpperCase();
    // Next, lets remove all the characters you didn't specify you care about (this leaves only capital A-Z)
    encrypt = encrypt.replace(/[^A-Z]/gm, '');
    // A quick and handy way to address each letter individually is to break the string into an array, with one letter per node (['H','E','L','L','O']):
    encrypt = encrypt.split('');
    // .map() loops through that array, setting letter to the value at each node and running the same process (on the following line) on each.
    encrypt = encrypt.map(letter=> {
        // letter.charCodeAt(0) gets us the charCode - the numeric equivalent of the letter ('A' is 65, 'Z' is 90, hence why I'm subtratcing 65 from each: to get us 0-25)
        var letterIndex = letter.charCodeAt(0) - 65;
        // Object.values(cypher) makes an array from JUST the encoded portion of the cypher from above (the letters in "Quotes"). We take the charCode we just worked out
        // ...and look it up inside the cyperArray. When we return it, it replaces letter in the encrypt array.
        return Object.values(cypher)[letterIndex];
    });
    // ...and finally, lets reassemble the array back into a string with our join, and write it out the document.
    document.write(encrypt.join(''));
    
}
```

There's a [working example, here](https://codepen.io/NerdyDeeds/pen/vYRPKpN/3abc8b51f043012b9909d412381418bc?editors=0010), as well.

There's a detailed explanation on each line.

Bonus (this will randomly re-seed/shuffle your cypher):

```
function seedCypher() {
    let cypherVals = [], randomLetter;
    while(cypherVals.length < 26){
        do {
            randomLetter = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 65);
        } while(cypherVals.indexOf(randomLetter) !== -1);
        cypherVals.push(randomLetter);
    }
    
    let cypherOutput = {};
    cypherVals.forEach((val, i)=>cypherOutput[String.fromCharCode(i+ 65)] = val);
    return cypherOutput;
}
cypher = seedCypher();
```

Have fun! ^_^

Oops! Missed your question about spaces:
The way you're currently handling it, add to your big line of vars `space=/ /g`, along with the corresponding

```
var result26 = space.test(encrypt)

  if(result === true) { 
    
    document.write(' ') 
    result=false   //A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
  }
```

Although the absolutely simplest way to perform a substitution cypher like this is by means of [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Running `var myString = encrypt.replace(/A/gi, 'X')` will replace every occurence (that's the 'g' after the slash: 'g'lobal) of the letter A (case insensitive - the 'i' after the 'g') with the letter X. Plus it can be daisy chained:

```
var myString = encrypt.replace(/A/gi, 'X')
                      .replace(/B/gi, 'O')
                      .replace(/C/gi, 'Y')
                      // ...etc., clear down to...
                      .replace(/Z/gi, 'T');
```

...which will serve to preserve your spaces and punctuation, too. And while it's still many lines more code than the streamlined example above, its super-easy to understand what's going on, and still MUCH shorter than how you'd been tackling it.

Comment: Thanks for helping but one more quick question, if I add the random part, how should I plan to decrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

I have refactored your code pretty much, hope this won't be a problem.
And changed `document.write` to `console.log` just to be more concise.

```js
// var answer = prompt("What cipher are you going to use 1 - 26", 1);
var answer = 1;
var encrypt = prompt("Enter text you want encrypted", "abc");
var result = "";

var encTable = {
  a: "x",
  A: "X",
  b: "j",
  B: "J",
  c: "p",
  C: "P"
  // please add all the others
};

if (answer == 1) {
  for (var gv = 0; gv < encrypt.length; gv++) {
    var char = encrypt[gv];
    result += encTable.hasOwnProperty(char) ? encTable[char] : char;
  }
}
console.log(result);
```